# No response from Volley JSONObject POST request

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I want to send a JSONObject POST request with Volley that takes a single parameter.  The code I've written, and included below, doesn't seem to receive any response in the onResponse method. I can't see what the problem might be to cause this.

I have checked on the server-side, and that is working as it should, with the PHP code echoing a JSON encoded array of data.

```
public void mySightingsJsonRequest() {


    //get username held in shared preferences (KMcE)
    HashMap<String, String> user = newSession.getUsername();
    final String username = user.get(SessionUtility.KEY_USERNAME);

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    try {
        obj.put("Username", username);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest mySightingsRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, ConnectionURLs.MY_SIGHTINGS, obj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: MySightings response");
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("server_response");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject sighting = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    int sightingRecordingNumber = sighting.getInt("Recording Number");
                    String sightingImgURL = sighting.getString("IMG");
                    String sightingCommonName = sighting.getString("Common Name");
                    String sightingUsername = sighting.getString("Submitted by");
                    double sightingLongitude = sighting.getDouble("Longitude");
                    double sightingLatitude = sighting.getDouble("Latitude");

                    mSightingList.add(new SightingSingle(sightingRecordingNumber, sightingImgURL, sightingCommonName, sightingUsername, sightingLatitude, sightingLongitude));

                }
                mMySightingsAdapter = new MySightingsAdapter(getActivity(), mSightingList);
                mMySightingRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMySightingsAdapter);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    mRequestQueue.add(mySightingsRequest);
}
```

Comment: use `Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: MySightings response "+ response.toString());` to see the response value

Answer (score 2):

Kieran M.

Please use the following code.

```
Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: MySightings response" + response.toString());
```

You should watch response value.

Now that's a one of methods for debug.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't get any response, the message doesn't appear in the logcat.

Comment: oh, yeah? I think the 'JsonObjectRequest mySightingsRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, ConnectionURLs.MY_SIGHTINGS, obj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()' line occurs error. now you couldn't return value about 'onResponse()'.

Comment: No JSONObjectRquest error is present in the Logcat when the program runs, it just seems to be unresponsive.

Comment: now, then try to use helper class, please. if you want, I'll send example class file and method.

Comment: I implemented a custom helper class and still there is no response.

Comment: public void onResponse(String response) {   
         // display response     
         Log.d("Response", response);
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179036/discussion-between-eric6-and-kieran-m).

Answer (score 0):

You can ask if the server can receive json

or try this code:

```
String reuquestBody = "Username="+username
```

and then replace obj with requestBody